# How to listen to this event data in ETH smart contract

Tags: python, ethereum, smartcontracts

I've tried to listen to a smart contract, but it says the
ABIFunctionNotFound: ("The function 'NewPair' was not found in this contract's abi. ", 'Are you sure you provided the correct contract abi?'). How could I call the NewPair event in the contract?

```
abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairEnumerableETH","name":"_enumerableETHTemplate","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairMissingEnumerableETH","name":"_missingEnumerableETHTemplate","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairEnumerableERC20","name":"_enumerableERC20Template","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairMissingEnumerableERC20","name":"_missingEnumerableERC20Template","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"_protocolFeeRecipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_protocolFeeMultiplier","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"contract ICurve","name":"bondingCurve","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"bool","name":"isAllowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"BondingCurveStatusUpdate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"target","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"bool","name":"isAllowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"CallTargetStatusUpdate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"poolAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"NFTDeposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"poolAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"NewPair","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newMultiplier","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ProtocolFeeMultiplierUpdate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"recipientAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"ProtocolFeeRecipientUpdate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"contract LSSVMRouter","name":"router","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"bool","name":"isAllowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"RouterStatusUpdate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"internalType":"address","name":"poolAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"TokenDeposit","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ICurve","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"bondingCurveAllowed","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"callAllowed","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_protocolFeeMultiplier","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeProtocolFeeMultiplier","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"_protocolFeeRecipient","type":"address"}],"name":"changeProtocolFeeRecipient","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"contract ERC20","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract IERC721","name":"nft","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract ICurve","name":"bondingCurve","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"assetRecipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"enum LSSVMPair.PoolType","name":"poolType","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"delta","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint96","name":"fee","type":"uint96"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"spotPrice","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"initialNFTIDs","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"initialTokenBalance","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct LSSVMPairFactory.CreateERC20PairParams","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"name":"createPairERC20","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairERC20","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract IERC721","name":"_nft","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract ICurve","name":"_bondingCurve","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"_assetRecipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"enum LSSVMPair.PoolType","name":"_poolType","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"_delta","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint96","name":"_fee","type":"uint96"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"_spotPrice","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"_initialNFTIDs","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"createPairETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairETH","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ERC20","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"depositERC20","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract IERC721","name":"_nft","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"ids","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"}],"name":"depositNFTs","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"enumerableERC20Template","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairEnumerableERC20","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"enumerableETHTemplate","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairEnumerableETH","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"potentialPair","type":"address"},{"internalType":"enum ILSSVMPairFactoryLike.PairVariant","name":"variant","type":"uint8"}],"name":"isPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"missingEnumerableERC20Template","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairMissingEnumerableERC20","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"missingEnumerableETHTemplate","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMPairMissingEnumerableETH","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"protocolFeeMultiplier","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"protocolFeeRecipient","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMRouter","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"routerStatus","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"allowed","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"wasEverAllowed","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ICurve","name":"bondingCurve","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"isAllowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"setBondingCurveAllowed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"target","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"isAllowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"setCallAllowed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract LSSVMRouter","name":"_router","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"isAllowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"setRouterAllowed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ERC20","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawERC20ProtocolFees","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawETHProtocolFees","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]
address = "0xb16c1342E617A5B6E4b631EB114483FDB289c0A4"
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

NewPair = contract.functions.NewPair.call()
print(web3.fromWei(NewPair))
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is from mainnet, you can go to etherscan, https://etherscan.io/address/0xb16c1342E617A5B6E4b631EB114483FDB289c0A4#code
Then copy the ABI from the textbox then replace it in your abi